# How to quantify strength of beta prior?

Tags: bayesian, beta-distribution, conjugate-prior, uninformative-prior

How would one interpret the strength of prior belief associated with a parameter with a prior beta(10,8) distribution, compared to a beta(0,0) prior, (with data from a binomial distribution)? Some intuition and calculations to support your answer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the standard Bayesian conjugate model:

$$\theta \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta),$$
$$X | \theta \sim \text{Bin}(n, \theta).$$

The posterior distribution for this model is:

$$\theta | x \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha + x, \beta + n-x).$$

In this model, the value $n_0 \equiv \alpha + \beta$ in the prior is a measure of prior strength that is sometimes called the number of *pseudo data points*.  Observation of the count value $x$ from $n$ trials adds to this to the posterior strength $n_0 + n$, so this is like you had $n_0$ pseudo data points and then added $n$ actual data points.